# The button expand is displayed on the page, despite the fact that it should be hidden before clicking on the button itself

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <head>

         <style>
               .b1{
                display:none;
                visibility: none;
                background-color:blue;}    
         </style>

    </head>        

    <body>
         <button class="offer-btn" onclick="openTab('b1');" type="button">DETAILS</button>

         <div id="b1" class="containerTab" >
           <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
          <h2>Box 1</h2>
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>

    </body>

    <script>
        function openTab(tabName) {
          var i, x;
          x = document.getElementsByClassName("containerTab");
          for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
             x[i].style.display = "none";
          }
          document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
```

**I want my button is closed when i enter my page.I tried to put script in head part but its still the same.**

Here is the picture when I enter:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cJ5X.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS makes use of a [**class** selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) (`.b1`) when you're looking for an [**ID** selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) (`#b1`).

Simply replacing this solves the problem:

```js
function openTab(tabName) {
  var i, x;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("containerTab");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#b1 {
  display: none;
  visibility: none;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="offer-btn" onclick="openTab('b1');" type="button">DETAILS</button>

<div id="b1" class="containerTab">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <h2>Box 1</h2>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Note that instead of `#b1`, you can alternatively use `.containerTab` if you prefer.

Also note that you'd be better of making use of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) rather than inline event handlers, though this isn't necessary to solve your problem.